# Summer/winter time - "daylight savings"

Tags: timezones

I have a wordpress site connected to an automated system that bases its work upon posts' modification date/time. 
In my timezone there have recently been a time swap and the operating system (linux) got it right, but wordpress still uses the "summer" time.

I have read that php returns the "summer" time always, but provides additional information `date(I)` 0 or 1 to indicate what time to use.

Wordpress doesn't seem to read that. ( Just as the worldclock plugin, but that's a whole new story:/ )

Anybody experienced with wordpress timezones? Is there a fix or a hack that could help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simple - My wordpress was set up for a general timezone. After picking a city it knew everything about daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP are you using?

As far as I remember WordPress has "forked" time management that is fully featured for PHP5, but falls back to older simpler code for PHP4.

For me it switched just fine and currently shows this in `General` settings:

> UTC time is 2010-11-08 8:47:07
>
> Local time is 2010-11-08 10:47:07
>
> This timezone is currently in standard time.
>
> Daylight saving time begins on: March 27, 2011 2:00 am.

Comment: I'm using php5. Wordpress (latest version 3.0.1) shows only local and utc time, no informatin about daylight saving.

Comment: Hmm... What timezone it is? I am not sure where it draws timezone information from (probably PHP).